# Java JarSigner error duplicate metadata.json in Appcelerator

Tags: java, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am attempting to build a `Android` application in `Appcelerator Studio` with `SDK 6.1.0.GA`.

I have `CommonJS` modules, currently we have two versions, one `pre SDK 6` with an `apiVerion of 2`, and one with `post SDK 6` with `apiVerion of 3`.

Both versions are in the `Application/modules` folder.

There are also `Alloy` modules as well.

```
[INFO] :   No aidl files to compile, continuing
[INFO] :   Generating i18n files
[DEBUG] :  Compiling localization files
[DEBUG] :  Merging en strings => /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/res/values/strings.xml
[INFO] :   Generating /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/res/values/theme.xml
[INFO] :   Running AAPT: /Applications/usr/sdk/Android/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/gen" "-M" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml" "-A" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/bin/assets" "-S" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/res" "-I" "/Applications/usr/sdk/Android/platforms/android-23/android.jar" "-F" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/bin/app.ap_" "--output-text-symbols" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/intermediates/bundles" "--no-version-vectors" "--auto-add-overlay" "--extra-packages" "ti.modules.titanium.ui:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview"
[DEBUG] :  Skipping duplicate jar file: /Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.map/3.0.1/lib/google-play-services-base.jar
[INFO] :   Building Java source files: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac "-J-Xmx1024M" "-encoding" "utf8" "-bootclasspath" "/Applications/usr/sdk/Android/platforms/android-23/android.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/kroll-v8.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-analytics.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/aps-analytics.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-android.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/kroll-common.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/titanium.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-multidex.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-filesystem.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-app.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-ui.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-media.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-appcompat.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-animated-vector-drawable.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-annotations.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-v4.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-v4-internal_impl.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-vector-drawable.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-cardview.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/cardview-v7-23.4.0.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-locale.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-network.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-xml.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-platform.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-gesture.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-contacts.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-geolocation.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-database.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-utils.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.audit/2.0.0/auditandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.beacons/2.0.0/beaconsandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.beaconstatus/2.0.0/beaconstatusandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.branding/2.0.0/brandingandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.cloud/2.0.0/cloudandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.db/2.0.0/dbandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.home/2.0.0/homeandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.homepage/2.0.0/homepageandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.logger/2.0.0/loggerandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.loyalty/2.0.0/loyaltyandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.mainwindow/2.0.0/mainwindowandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.notifications/2.0.0/notificationsandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.phonehandler/2.0.0/phonehandlerandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.preferences/2.0.0/preferencesandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.referral/2.0.0/referralandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.registrationmanager/2.0.0/registrationmanagerandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.restcalls/2.0.0/restcallsandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.restcore/2.0.0/restcoreandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.router/2.0.0/routerandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.screens/2.0.0/screensandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.settings/2.0.0/settingsandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.usersettings/2.0.0/usersettingsandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.utilities/2.0.0/utilitiesandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.venuemap/2.0.0/venuemapandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.wayfind/2.0.0/wayfindandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.webview/2.0.0/webviewandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.webviewpage/2.0.0/webviewpageandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.android.wayfind/2.0.0/wayfind.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.android.wayfind/2.0.0/lib/indoors-library-surface.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.youorder/2.0.0/youorderandroid.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/bencoding.android.tools/0.50/androidtools.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/com.liferay.beacons/0.4.3/liferay.beacons.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/com.liferay.beacons/0.4.3/lib/radius.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/com.shareourideas.locale/1.0/locale.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/com.wwl.canvas/2.0.0/canvas.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/dk.napp.drawer/2.0.0/nappslide.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/ti.barcode/3.0.0/barcode.jar:/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/ti.barcode/3.0.0/lib/core.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/4.0.3/cloudpush.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/4.0.3/lib/aps-cloudpush-1.1.4.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/4.0.3/lib/google-play-services-base.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/4.0.3/lib/google-play-services-gcm.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/4.0.3/lib/google-play-services-iid.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.map/3.0.1/map.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.map/3.0.1/lib/google-play-services-map.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/kroll-apt.jar:/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/lib/titanium-verify.jar:Manifest.class:R.class:AssetCryptImpl.class:RelActivity.class:RelAppInfo.class:RelApplication.class" "-d" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/bin/classes" "-proc:none" "-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "@/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/java-sources.txt"
[INFO] :   Running dexer: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-Xmx1024M" "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" "-Djava.ext.dirs=/Applications/usr/sdk/Android/platform-tools" "-jar" "/Applications/usr/sdk/Android/build-tools/23.0.1/lib/dx.jar" "--dex" "--multi-dex" "--output=/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/bin/dexfiles" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/bin/classes" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/lib/titanium-verify.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.audit/2.0.0/auditandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.beacons/2.0.0/beaconsandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.beaconstatus/2.0.0/beaconstatusandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.branding/2.0.0/brandingandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.cloud/2.0.0/cloudandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.db/2.0.0/dbandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.home/2.0.0/homeandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.homepage/2.0.0/homepageandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.logger/2.0.0/loggerandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.loyalty/2.0.0/loyaltyandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.mainwindow/2.0.0/mainwindowandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.notifications/2.0.0/notificationsandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.phonehandler/2.0.0/phonehandlerandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.preferences/2.0.0/preferencesandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.referral/2.0.0/referralandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.registrationmanager/2.0.0/registrationmanagerandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.restcalls/2.0.0/restcallsandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.restcore/2.0.0/restcoreandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.router/2.0.0/routerandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.screens/2.0.0/screensandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.settings/2.0.0/settingsandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.usersettings/2.0.0/usersettingsandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.utilities/2.0.0/utilitiesandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.venuemap/2.0.0/venuemapandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.wayfind/2.0.0/wayfindandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.webview/2.0.0/webviewandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.webviewpage/2.0.0/webviewpageandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.android.wayfind/2.0.0/wayfind.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.android.wayfind/2.0.0/lib/indoors-library-surface.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/au.com.mobilogica.youorder/2.0.0/youorderandroid.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/bencoding.android.tools/0.50/androidtools.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/com.liferay.beacons/0.4.3/liferay.beacons.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/com.liferay.beacons/0.4.3/lib/radius.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/com.shareourideas.locale/1.0/locale.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/com.wwl.canvas/2.0.0/canvas.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/dk.napp.drawer/2.0.0/nappslide.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/ti.barcode/3.0.0/barcode.jar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/modules/android/ti.barcode/3.0.0/lib/core.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/4.0.3/cloudpush.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/4.0.3/lib/aps-cloudpush-1.1.4.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/4.0.3/lib/google-play-services-base.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/4.0.3/lib/google-play-services-gcm.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.cloudpush/4.0.3/lib/google-play-services-iid.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.map/3.0.1/map.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.map/3.0.1/lib/google-play-services-map.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/kroll-v8.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-analytics.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/aps-analytics.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-android.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/jaxen-1.1.1.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/kroll-common.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/titanium.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-multidex.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-filesystem.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-app.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-ui.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-media.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-appcompat.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-animated-vector-drawable.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-annotations.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-v4.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-v4-internal_impl.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/android-support-vector-drawable.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-cardview.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/cardview-v7-23.4.0.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-locale.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-network.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-xml.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-platform.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-gesture.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-contacts.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-geolocation.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-database.jar" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-utils.jar"
[INFO] :   Creating unsigned apk
[INFO] :   Processing /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/bin/dexfiles
[INFO] :   Processing /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/src
[INFO] :   Writing unsigned apk: /Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/bin/app-unsigned.apk
[INFO] :   Using MD5withRSA signature algorithm
[INFO] :   Signing apk: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jarsigner "-sigalg" "MD5withRSA" "-digestalg" "SHA1" "-keystore" "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/dev_keystore" "-storepass" "*******" "-signedjar" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/bin/REL.apk" "/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/bin/app-unsigned.apk" "tidev"
[ERROR] :  Failed to sign apk:
[ERROR] :  jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: metadata.json
```

So I am not sure where the duplicate entry exists.

One thing I note is that this line:

```
[INFO] :   "-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "@/Users/chris/Ti/APPCGenieWS/GenieProject/Genie.Alloy/build/android/java-sources.txt"
```

Sets the target as `1.6`, though I have set everywhere that I can find to `1.8`, so I am not sure if this could be a part of the problem or just a red herring. Sorry had to trim this for space reasons.

System:

- Mac OSX 10.12.5
- Appcelerator CLI 6.2.2
- Appcelerator SDK 6.1.0.GA
- JDK jdk1.8.0_31

Note: I just downloaded 6.1.1.GA and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [similar duplicate entry](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23502) issue on regular android modules compiled with certain 6.x sdks, but I haven't run across something like this for compiled CommonJS modules.  Give this a try:

1. In your app project, navigate to `modules/android/modulename/version`
2. Make a **backup** of `modulename.jar` in case the following breaks something
3. Do `unzip -l modulename.jar`.  Look for the `metadata.json` file.
4. If it is there, do a `zip -d modulename.jar path/to/metadata.json`

Then try rebuilding your project.

Comment: Yeah, I did look at that one quite closely, it appears very much unrelated, and that was fixed in 6.0.2, and I have moved to 6.1.0 and now 6.1.1.

I will give this a try, we have about 15 modules or so :)

Comment: It was fixed in 6.0.2, but then the module itself needs to be recompiled with the newer sdk.  Just building the app with the newer sdk won't do it.

Comment: Yes, I rebuilt every module after upgrading to 6. I did read the Release Notes about the change to the V8 engine.

Comment: Though I did build them with `appc run -p android --build-only`.

Comment: If I use the ant build method, I get many different errors regarding AssetCryptImpl.java, so I don't believe this method is the one used, if I build it from the studio, it seems to using an equivalent (though longer) version of what I mentioned above.

Comment: What happened when you tried the steps to remove the metadata.json file?

Comment: Sorry Adam, I haven't gotten back to that point just yet, got put onto other tasks. I am getting back to that shortly, will let you know.

Comment: Okay, I removed the metadata.json from every jar that had one (ie all my CommonJS modules).

I still get the same error.

It is in the generated app-unsigned.apk:

`unzip -v ../app-unsigned.apk | grep metadata`


     432  Defl:N      231  47% 06-30-2017 06:24 9bc0461a  metadata.json

     189  Defl:N      132  30% 06-30-2017 06:24 3320550d  metadata.json

Comment: Sounds like it could be a new bug unfortunately. You can file a ticket here: https://jira.appcelerator.org

Comment: Yeah, I will have to figure out how to create a test app which reproduces the problem. So thanks for your help.

I am gonna mark this as the answer as I think this is the acceptable approach.